# Windows Service Container

Tags: wcf, windows-services, mef

For my projects I need quite often to create windows services.

I need them for scheduling operations, file system watching, asynchronous or long running side tasks (backup files, sending messages, check incoming mail to process, notifications etc).

I also use them to expose WCF services that are cross applications in the enterprise.

The self hosted scenario seems to me more appropriate as we are still on II6 that is quite limited (only http) for exposing WCF.

Most of) the services need also to expose some kind of administration interface (web or desktop) for reporting, starting and stopping the various services etc.

Seems strange to me that a "host container" that leverages most of these features (host, install new services, remote ui for admin, exposing wcf, scheduling etc) with some kind of mef plugins doesn't already exists.

What are the options if I do not want to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

There is one host server in development (Microsoft) - codename Dublin.

The possible option would be to create one Windows Service - host application, which will load all of your WCF services and create ServiceHost for each of them (for instance, through reflection).
Having only one windows service would make it easy to administer all service hosts (you wouldn't have to administer windows service, but only in-process hosts).